# Question about product measure

Tags: measure-theory, product-measure

Let me define first: let us have $(\Omega_1,S_1,\mu_1)$ and $(\Omega_2,S_2,\mu_2)$ be measure spaces. If $E\subseteq \Omega_1\times\Omega_2$ then the $x$-slice of $E$ is defined by $E^x=\{y\in\Omega_2: (x,y)\in E\}$ we have the following assertions:

(1) If $E=A_1\times A_2$,$A_1\in B_1$ and $A_2\in B_2$, and if $x\in \Omega_1$ then $E^x\in B_2$.

(2) The function $x\rightarrow \mu_2(E^x) $ is $B_1$-measurable.

I have understood part (1) but in part (2) we are saying that $\mu_2(E^x)$ as a function of $x$ is $B_1$-measurable, I want to know how this function is defined, I mean the domain and codomain of this, I am totally confused here.

Comment: the domain of the map $x\mapsto \mu_2(E^x)$ is clearly $\Omega _1$, and the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: so basically it is $E^x:\Omega_1\to \Omega_2$ and $\mu_2:\Omega_2\to \mathbb{R}$ right? and we got the above map with composition.

Comment: no, the map $x\mapsto E^x$ goes from $\Omega _1$ to $S_2$, and $\mu_2$, as it is a measure, goes from $S_2$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: But we define $E^x=\{y\in\Omega_2: (x,y)\in E\}$

Comment: yes, $E^x$ is a **set** (a mesurable one, indeed). P.S.: in the body of the question you had a typographic error: you wrote $B_j$ instead of $S_j$ (for $j=1,2$)